# Tensorflow Index File Utility

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've been looking for a clear answer, but couldn't find until now.

In Tensorflow, after the training executing, 4 files are generated:

.meta,
.data,
.index and
checkpoint

What is the utility of the .index file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .index file holds an immutable key-value table linking a serialized tensor name and where to find data in its .data files